# vb.net console application crashes

Tags: vb.net, console-application

i have created a very simple console application in vb.net that emails me some info from the db daily. everythign works in my dev environment, however when i move it out to production and try to run the executable, i get the following error message:
"A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. please close the program"

i have put in some exception checks in the code:

```
Dim output As String
        Try
            output = FormatIndividualRecords(False)
            'SaveToFile(output, "NIndividualRecords.doc")


            ''email files
            'Emailusers()
        Catch e As Exception
            WriteLine(e.Message)
        End Try
```

and i expected the error to show up on the application console, but it does not, is there another way for me to see what error is being thrown? there is no development environment set up in production (no visual studio, etc), is there maaybe a log that that i can look at? how do i catch the error that's causing the app to fail?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: i chagned the       WriteLine(e.Message) to console.write(e.message) now there appealrs to be a message on the console when i run the application, but it blinks too fast and closes, i don't have time to see what it is... how can i get the console application to remain open?

Comment: Have you checked first that you have all the correct libraries included with the application?  You can use assembly bind logging to validate.

Comment: Is it possible you have code somewhere outside of the Try/Catch that is throwing an exception?

Comment: @mellamokb - i have included everything i needed in my dev environemtn and build the project. i thought when i build it into an exe, it automatically adds all the libraries to it?

Comment: @vcsjones - no :( i put it everywhere

Comment: @xrum - place Console.ReadLine() after the call to Console.WriteLine(e.Message).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try directing output of the app to a file, rather than to the console...

```
MyProgram.exe > log.txt
```

Comment: i was just double clicking the .exe file from the explorer. it works in command prompt. thanks! i see the error in the log file :) "Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException.  This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed.Object reference not set to an instance of an object."